# Simplify 1/(Math.pow(2, y) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a case where I want to return

```
y = 1/2^x
```

basically

```
1
1/2
1/4
1/8
...
```

This is the best I've come up with

```
function halfing (depth){
    return 1/(Math.pow(2, (depth) ))
}
```

Is there a simpler and easier to follow way of doing this?

Comment: No there isn't really a simpler way to do that

Comment: Your title does not match your question. Whatever your question is. It seems to be "is there a way to do <thing> that is not the canonical and simple way to do <thing>". Why? What makes the canonical and simple way to do this somehow unacceptable for you?

Comment: Atmost it can be Math.pow(0.5, depth)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's hard to tell if it's cannonical and simple if you don't know the alternatives.

Comment: @Himmators: I'm asking you why you think you need alternatives. There must be a reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [a Wikibooks article on mathematics](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Primary_Mathematics/Powers,_roots,_and_exponents):

> A negative exponent simply means you take the reciprocal (one over the number) of the base first, then apply the exponent.

So you can move the reciprocal into the `Math.pow` call:

```
function halfing(depth) { 
   Math.pow(2,-depth);
}
```

Comment: It's debatable as to whether this is easier to follow. Besides, you should _explain_ this code dump. Tell the OP why `x^-y` is equivalent to `1/(x^y)`.

Comment: Yes. But the title is "Simplify *js code* in javascript". Well... it's less code :-) (I was looking for a resource)

Comment: Not simpler. Simplified.

Comment: To simplify something _means_ to make it simpler. By definition.

Comment: "Simple(r)" is subjective and it depends by reader's knowledge. There is no other reference (in this context).
"Simpli(fy|ied)" has 2 possible reference in this context: 1) to be more simple, 2) to reduce (an equation, fraction, etc) to a simpler form by cancellation of common factors, regrouping of terms in the same variable, etc. (reference(dot)com)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit you might want to take this discussion to http://english.stackexchange.com/ ;)

Comment: By the way.. we really want to discuss about word?

Comment: @Himmators: I don't. That place is horrible! Besides, there is no need as chumkiu has just contradicted himself.

Comment: @chumkiu: And both of them are exactly what I said. "To be more simple" "to a simpler form". You previously rejected that idea that "simplified" would make something "simpler".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I do agree with you that my question does not perfectly describe what I was after. Sometimes the abstract concept that you are looking for is hard to capture in a word. chumiku did provide an alternative way that may be useful in some instances. We made the internet a little better place, isn't that good?

Comment: @Himm Yes, it is. I was only providing some feedback. I did not ask for this to turn into an English debate!